# Magento 2.4.6. Can't display Layout in the adminpage

Tags: magento2.4.6

For some reason on a new page I created on the admin, I can't pass text to Body.

Is there any way to suggest what I'm missing?

My code:

app\code\Dev\RestApi\etc\adminhtml\menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Backend:etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Dev_RestApi::dev_module" title="Dev Module" module="Dev_RestApi" sortOrder="10" parent="Magento_Backend::content" resource="Dev_RestApi::dev_module"/>
        <add id="Dev_RestApi::dev_module_PriceInfo_Module" title="PriceInfo_Module" module="Dev_RestApi" sortOrder="10" parent="Dev_RestApi::dev_module" action="dev/controller/index" resource="Dev_RestApi::dev_module_PriceInfo_Module"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

app\code\Dev\RestApi\view\adminhtml\layout\token_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="page.title">
        <action method="setPageTitle">
            <argument name="title" xsi:type="string">Dev Module</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Template" template="Dev_RestApi::form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

app\code\Dev\RestApi\view\adminhtml\templates\form.phtml

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

app\code\Dev\RestApi\Controller\Adminhtml\Controller\index.php

```
namespace Dev\RestApi\Controller\Adminhtml\Controller;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Dev Module Page'));

        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setTemplate('Dev_RestApi::form.phtml');
        }

        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

[image: See only title]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this part of your `PHP` :

```
   $block = $resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('content');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setTemplate('Dev_RestApi::form.phtml');
    }
```

else you replace the content block that has some other blocks as children by the form only and it most probably prevents your form from being displayed.

it is also nice to add name and (before|after) attribute to the block tag in `XML` to avoid strange result.

Here is an example of xml : `vendor/magento/module-analytics/view/adminhtml/layout/adminhtml_dashboard_index.xml`

Comment: I forgot about that.Thx.